# Mac OS X installation of emacs doesn't auto-load certain libraries (?)

Tags: macos, emacs, osx-lion, toolbar, libraries

It seems that some emacs installations on Mac OS X do not auto-load certain libraries. Here's a specific example of what I'm talking about:

When I eval the elisp command "(tool-bar-mode -1)" I get the error:
"Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function tool-bar-mode)"

This is just one instance. I get similar errors for example with "(scroll-bar-mode -1)" and others.

Ok, which emacs installations am I using? I have noticed this issue with:

- the default emacs 22 installation that comes with Mac OS X 10.6 and 10.7
- emacs 23; both the MacPorts and Fink installations on Mac OS X 10.6 and 10.7
- emacs 24 MacPorts installation on Mac OS X 10.6 and 10.7
- Note: all of the above were terminal (i.e. non-windowed) emacs

I have NOT noticed this issue with the following installations:

- any linux installation of emacs 22+
- the Cocoa-based Emacs.app installation (available here: http://emacsformacosx.com/)

In order to deal with this I've had to add to include library calls such as "(require 'tool-bar)" in my ".emacs" file just to ward off the errors. Why is this happening? What is effectively different between these installations?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just running Emacs from the command line, you don't need to turn off the toolbar or scrollbars, since they don't do anything in that environment -- those modes are for GUIs.

However, if you'd a .emacs for GUIs and CLI, use something like this:

```
(if window-system
    (tool-bar-mode -1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, my question was not how to deal with the specific manifestations of this behavior; I have already instituted work-arounds like the one you described. My questions was *why* this happens at all, as the equivalent linux installations _inside the terminal_, don't need this sort of special treatment. I want a deeper explanation of the underlying problem.